# TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'WebDataRocks'

Tags: webdatarocks

I have a react application and I'm trying to use WebDataRocks to render data from my bd. But, when I try to build I'm getting an error that says:

TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'WebDataRocks'.

I tried several stuff, but I still receive the error. The only things that's working is when I add a flag of ignoring the typescript type of and index.d.js. But, I can't change the modules because it's not gonna work when I send the code for prod area.

My guess is  the file should be tsx not ts. But, again I can't change the modules.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I kindly suggest creating a new project and embedding WebDataRocks to check how modules should be imported.

#### Here is a short guide:

1. If you don’t have a React+TS application yet, create one by running this command in the console:
   `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`
   `cd my-app`
2. Get the WebDataRocks React module from npm:
   `npm install react-webdatarocks`
3. Add WebDataRocks’ styles to the `src/index.tsx` file:
   `import 'webdatarocks/webdatarocks.css'`
4. Import the WebDataRocksReact module to the src/App.tsx file:
   `import * as WebDataRocksReact from 'react-webdatarocks';`
5. Open src/App.tsx and add WebDataRocks there using the WebDataRocksReact.Pivot component:

```
function App() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <WebDataRocksReact.Pivot 
         toolbar={true}
         componentFolder="https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/"
         width="100%"
         report="https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/reports/report.json"
        />
      </div>
    );
}
```

6. Run your application:
   `npm start`
7. Open `http://localhost:3000/` in the browser — WebDataRocks is embedded into your React+TS project.